# Laravel Route URI: Add or condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have written a route with uri, which accepts `/app/12/password`

```
Route::get('app/{id}/password', 'AppController@pwd')->name('apwd');
```

Now i want to extend it to also accept `/app/12/pwd`. What is standard way to do this, since i can't write different route. I tried.

```
Route::get('app/{id}/(pwd|password)', 'AppController@pwd')->name('apwd');
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Route::get('app/{id}/{param}', 'AppController@pwd')
->where('param', 'pwd|password') // param will accept either 'pwd' or 'password'
->name('apwd');
```

Comment: Looked in to Laravel Route class, could not do this just by changing uri part.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to add another route for this:

```
Route::get('app/{id}/password', 'AppController@pwd')->name('apwd');
Route::get('app/{id}/pwd', 'AppController@pwd')->name('apwd.pwd');
```

Comment: I can't there is check further in code which uses route name to resolve some dependencies.